# VBA to duplicate large dataset using array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have data on sheet A and want to duplicate it on sheet B. Because it is a lot of data, I do not want to use copy-paste. If I really simplify it, this is my code. My ranges change although I made it sort of fixed in this simplified code. I do not want to use something like range("A1:BBB100000") since my range will change. I get 1004 error "Application-defined or object-defined error". What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim origin(1 to 100000, 1 to 100000) as Variant
Dim dest(1 to 100000, 1 to 100000) as Variant

Set A=Worksheets("A")
Set B=Worksheets("B")
Vrow=100000

set origin=A.range(cells(1,1),cells(Vrow, Vrow))
set dest=B.range(cells(1,1),cells(Vrow, Vrow))
dest=origin
```

Comment: You get an error because of `cells(Vrow, Vrow)` when `Vrow = 100 000` That's too many columns. Also `dest=origin` should be something like `dest = origin.value`, or maybe better `dest = origin.value2` but the latter is only if you need no number formats to copy.

Comment: p.s. to get the max number of columns try a formula `=columns(1:1)` or a code for vba `Rows(1).Columns.Count`

Comment: @Vitalizzare I didn't even notice the amount of columns. Good spot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the array. Only generate an array if your actually going to do any calculations on it. If you just want to do value -> value then that's what you do (as shown below).

Remember to always declare all your variables as well.

```
Dim A As Worksheet, B As Worksheet, Vrow As Long
Set A = Worksheets("A")
Set B = Worksheets("B")
Vrow = 100000

B.Range(B.Cells(1, 1), B.Cells(Vrow, Vrow)).Value = A.Range(A.Cells(1, 1), A.Cells(Vrow, Vrow)).Value
```

Comment: That was my first thought but I did not know that I needed to put the sheet name to the cells command so it did not work...... B.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Vrow, Vrow)).Value = A.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Vrow, Vrow)).Value

Comment: Yes you need to add to that as even though you have it in the Range function, it is it's own function so needs to have the sheet set otherwise it defaults to the active sheet, which then conflicts with the Range function. Your code of array wouldn't have worked anyway as you had a couple other things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Range Values to Another Worksheet

```
Sub CopyValues()

    Const sName As String = "A"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    Const dName As String = "B"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(sFirstCellAddress)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sfCell.CurrentRegion
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    
End Sub


Sub CopyValuesShorter()

    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B").Range("A1") _
        .Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    
End Sub


Sub CopyValuesShortest()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B").Range("A1") _
            .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
    
End Sub
```